# How can I use linux commands in Windows 10 natively?

Tags: linux, windows-10, command-line, powershell

I tried using simple linux commands in windows cmd and that does not work. However, Windows Powershell supports some commands, such as `ls`. I tried using other commands, such as `ll`, `du` and it did not work. Is there any way to use linux commands in Windows natively? I do not want to use cygwin etc.

Comment: Yes; Use the beta WSL Windows 10 feature: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux otherwise learn Powershell and/or accept Cygwin as an option

Comment: powershell does not accept all linux commands.

Comment: Of course it doesn't.  It has its own equivalent commands, these commands you want to use, are Linux programs.  So you can either use WSL or Cygwin

Comment: "ALL" Linux commands is a pretty broad thing. I have a good subset of them including du from GOW  - but you can find linux boxen without all the linux commands. In fact nothing has *all* the commands, just often a common subset of them

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/422163/is-there-a-better-more-unix-like-command-line-shell-for-windows/782766#782766

Comment: This post would be better placed at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Here is a lot of info about the new Win10 integrated `bash` shell and what you can do with it:  https://www.howtogeek.com/265900/everything-you-can-do-with-windows-10s-new-bash-shell/

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing Powershell, and WSL.

Powershell is a scripting language and enviroment for windows, which has almost nothing to do with a linux 'shell'. They arent' the same

What you likely want to use, is 'Linux on Windows', or [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)

Another option you can use is Cygwin, which gives you a linux shell, on windows.

Comment: WSL would be the only way to get "all" or "vast majority" of Linux commands without something like Cygwin which isn't Linux and has limited support and only has those commands that have been recompile's to be compatible

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options for *common* commands - ll is a alias  for ls -alf (and I'm not sure for the windows equivilent for an alias.).

[Gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) is a native *theoretically portable* package of native windows ports. Its theoretically portable cause it adds itself to path so things work as they would on linux. It contains a large subset of common tools

A quick test suggests du works, as does ls -alf (what I believe ll does).

There's also busybox ports for windows that would probably do too.

Comment: There is also [Hamilton Shell](https://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm) by our very own [Nicole Hamilton](https://superuser.com/users/156601/nicole-hamilton) which won't give you "all" Linux commands but a good chunk (or similar commands).